# XSL - Test a boolean value

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint, boolean

I've got a problem with a XSLT code in SharePoint 2010. 
I'm not very expierienced with XSLT, but I think, I am able to read the code.
From the SharePoint query I got this XML code:

```
<Result>
    <id>2</id>
    <workid>160</workid>
    <rank>67119018</rank>
    <title>Angebot.pdf</title>
    <author_multival>User, Name</author_multival>
    <author>User, Name</author>
    <size>440631</size>
    <url>http://portal.url.de/sites/IT/Projects/Angebot.pdf</url>
    <urlEncoded>http%3A%2F%2Fportal%2Eurl%2Ede%2Fsites%2FIT%2FProjects%2FAngebot%2Epdf</urlEncoded>
    <description></description>
    <write>21.03.2014</write>
    <sitename>http://portal.url.de/sites/IT/Projects</sitename>
    <collapsingstatus>0</collapsingstatus>
    <hithighlightedsummary>User, Name <ddd /> <c0>SharePoint</c0>:Z-Drive <ddd /> Costs</hithighlightedsummary>
    <hithighlightedproperties>
            <HHTitle>Angebot.pdf</HHTitle>
            <HHUrl>http://portal.url.de/sites/IT/Projects/Angebot.pdf</HHUrl>
    </hithighlightedproperties>
    <contentclass>STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary</contentclass>
    <isdocument>True</isdocument>
    <picturethumbnailurl></picturethumbnailurl>
    <serverredirectedurl></serverredirectedurl>
    <sharepoint-invalid>False</sharepoint-invalid>
    <fileextension_multival>PDF</fileextension_multival>
    <fileextension>PDF</fileextension>
    <ows_metadatafacetinfo>Projectx0020Name|Project Name|o3PIYhfa0kOegAKxi60qtQ==|S7ZoMTb2ikCAhuSFlC+sGA==|#43318cf9-39f5-461c-a4d0-bd2653612092|SharePoint:Z-Drive;#Projectx0020Documentx0020Category0|Project Document Category|o3PIYhfa0kOegAKxi60qtQ==|zRewJpp710mnJ0bWknAb2Q==|#d8f09524-a0dc-4324-97c3-1d566e4af75f|Costs;#</ows_metadatafacetinfo>
    <popularsocialtags />
    <imageurl imageurldescription="">/_layouts/images/pdf16.gif</imageurl>
```

Now I need to check the value of

```
<sharepoint-invalid>False</sharepoint-invalid>
```

in XSLT.
I tried the following code, but it won't work. I don't know how to check the boolean values correctly, because in the search is always **"Valid"** displayed.

Here is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$SharePoint-Invalid = 'True'">
            <span style="color:#EF1317;font-weight:bold;">Invalid</span>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
            <span style="color:#199039;font-weight:bold;">Valid</span>
    </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose>
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the definition of the variable `$SharePoint-Invalid`?

Comment: The XSLT code starts with the following lines [`code`]<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:srwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/searchresults/runtime"
    xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:param name="Keyword" />
  <xsl:param name="ResultsBy" />
  ...
  <xsl:param name="SharePoint-Invalid" />
  <xsl:param name="IsDesignMode">True</xsl:param>[`code`] So I added the line <xsl:param name="SharePoint-Invalid" />

Comment: In this case, `$SharePoint-Invalid` is a parameter. Do you know how this XSLT code is invoked?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I just have to add this XSLT code to a webpart of SharePoint.

Comment: But thank you very much for your hint. I figured it out now. I had to remove the parameter and the parameter sign before and all had to be in lowercase. Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
Here is the code:

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="sharepoint-invalid = 'True'">
          <span style="color:#EF1317;font-weight:bold;">Document Invalid</span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <span style="color:#199039;font-weight:bold;">Document Valid</span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
```

The problem was, if I understood correctly, that I checked a parameter and the value itself. Also the variable had to be in lowercase letters to test.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Now you are not using a parameter at all (neither a variable). Without `$`, `sharepoint-invalid` refers to the input XML - where this element is really present.